# Are all deities mentioned to be limbs of Lord Shiva?

Tags: brahman, shaivism

My interest is in a verse from Mahābhārata. Therein tis stated that,
nārāyanasya cāngani sarvadaivāni bhārata
"All deities are like limbs of Nārāyana for He is the embodiment of all Devas" ~ Sabha Parva 2.35.29

Are there any similar verses for Lord Shiva?

Comment: I don't know about all dieties but
As per Shiva Purāṇa, it was Shiva who created Brahma and Vishnu from his right and left sides respectively.

Comment: @Tezz maybe you could help out here?

Answer (score 2):

There are many such examples let me give you some.

> *“yo ‘sṛjad dakṣiṇād aṅgād brahmāṇaṃ lokasaṃbhavam | vāmapārśvāt tathā viṣṇuṃ lokarakṣārtham īśvaraḥ | yugānte caiva saṃprāpte rudram aṅgāt sṛjat prabhuḥ |” (MBH 13:14:183)*
>
> ***“Thou art he that hadst created from thy right side the Grandsire Brahma, the Creator of all things. Thou art he that hadst created from thy left side Vishnu for protecting the Creation. Thou art that puissant Lord who didst create Rudra (the destroyer deity Kalagni-Rudra) when the end of the Yuga came and when the Creation was once more to be dissolved”.***

> *bāṇa uvāca |
> devadeva mahādeva śaraṇā gatavatsala |
> tvāṃ namāmi maheśāna dīnabandho dayānidhe || kṛtā mayi kṛpātīva kṛpāsāgara śaṃkara |
> garvopahāritassarvaḥ prasannena mama prabho || tvaṃ brahma paramātmā hi sarvavyāpyakhileśvaraḥ |
> brahmāṃḍatanurugreśo virāṭ sarvānvitaḥ paraḥ || nābhirnabho'gnirvadanamaṃbu reto diśaḥ śrutiḥ |
> dyauśśīrṣamaṃghrirurvī te manaścandrastava prabho || dṛgarko jaṭharaṃ vārddhirbhujeṃdro dhiṣaṇā vidhiḥ |
> prajāpatirvisargaśca dharmo hi hṛdayaṃ tava || romāṇyauṣadhayo nātha keśā jalamucastava |
> guṇāstrayastrinetrāṇi sarvātmā puruṣo bhavān || brāhmaṇaṃ te mukhaṃ prāhurbāhuṃ kṣatriyameva ca |
> ūrujaṃ vaiśyamāhuste pādajaṃ śūdrameva ca || tvameva sarvadopāsyassarvairjīvairmaheśvara |
> tvāṃ bhajanparamāṃ muktiṃ labhate puruṣo dhruvam || yastvāṃ visṛjate martya ātmānaṃ priyamīśvaram |
> viparyayendriyārthārthaṃ viṣamattyamṛtaṃ tyajan || viṣṇurbrahmā'tha vibudhā munayaścāmalāśayāḥ |
> sarvātmanā prapannāstvāṃ śaṃkaraṃ priyamīśvaram || (Sri Shiva Maha Puranam 2.5:5:56:21-30).*
>
> ***Bāṇa said:— O great lord, lord of the gods, favourably disposed to those who seek refuge in you, O great lord, I bow to you, O kinsman of the distressed, O storehouse of mercy. O Śiva, O ocean of sympathy, you have taken pity on me. O lord, being delighted with me you have removed my arrogance. You are Brahman, the great soul, the all-pervading lord. _ Your body is the whole cosmos. You are Ugra, Īśa, Virāṭ, the great, accompanied by everything. O lord, your navel is the sky, mouth is the fire, semen is the water, ear the quarters, head the heaven, foot the earth and mind the moon. Your eye is the sun, the stomach the ocean, the arm Indra, and the intellect Brahmā. Your excretion is Prajāpati and your heart is Dharma. O lord, your hairs are the herbs and plants, your tresses the clouds, your eyes the three attributes. You are the Puruṣa, the soul of all. They (Vedas) call Brāhmaṇa your mouth, Kṣatriya your arms, Vaiśya your thighs and Śūdra your feet. O lord Śiva, you alone deserve to be adored by all living beings. A person worshipping you certainly derives liberation. O lord, the man who forsakes you, the favourite Ātman, for the adverse objects of sense, swallows poison forsaking nectar. Viṣṇu, Brahmā, the gods and the sages of pure mind, in every respect resort to you, the favourite lord.***

> ***Rudra is the embodiment of all Devas. All devas are merely different manifestations (parts) of Sri Rudra Himself. On the right side of Rudra, there is the sun, then the four-headed Brahma, and then three Agnis (fires). On the left side, there exist Sri Umadevi, and also Vishnu and Soma (moon) (Rudra hridhaya upanishad )***
>
> ***Uma Herself is the form of Vishnu. Vishnu Himself is the form of the moon. Therefore, those who worship Lord Vishnu, worship Lord Siva Himself. And those who worship Lord Siva, worship Lord Vishnu. Those who envy and hate Sri Rudra, are actually hating Sri Vishnu. Those who decry Lord Siva, decry Lord Vishnu Himself. (Rudra hridhaya upanishad )***
>
> ***Rudra is the generator of the seed. Vishnu is the embryo of the seed. Siva Himself is Brahma and Brahma Himself is Agni. Rudra is full of Brahma and Vishnu. The whole world is full of Agni and Soma. The masculine gender is Lord Siva. The feminine gender is Sri Bhavani Devi. All the mobile and immobile creation of this universe, is filled up with Uma and Rudra. The Vyakta is Sri Uma, and the Avyakta is Lord Siva. ( Rudra hridaya upanishad )***
>
> ***The effect is Vishnu. The action is Brahma. The cause is Siva. For the benefit of the worlds. Rudra has taken these three forms. ( Rudra hridaya upanishad).***

> *"dhAmno yasya hariragro.atha vishvo brahmA putraiH sahitashcha dvijAshcha |
> parAbhUtA bhavane yasya somo juShatveSha shreyase sAdhu goptA |” (Harivamsa Parva 2-72-58).*
>
> *“For our benefit, let lord shiva along with uma be pleased with us, **whose splendour's main parts are lord viShNu and brahma, along with his sons, the sages such as sanaka, marIcha, whose abode they are unable to enter and who protects the good men”.***

I hope this clarifies your queries.